# jQuery Masonry insert error

Tags: jquery, json, append

I am trying to read a JSON file that contains my tweets and insert them into the Masonry container after init but I keep getting an error that I cannot append before the Masonry is initialized. Anyway to get around this?

I've also tried using isotope with the init callback calling a function that then pulls in the tweets but still get the same error.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant JavaScript you've attempted?

Answer (score 0):

This mean you must setup the "stage" before.

```
$('.element').masonry();
```

Once this is done, you can the append and call `appended` method.

But if there's nothing in your mosaique, just append your tweets, and the init masonry normally (without calling `appended` method).